# codeigniter two dimensional superglobal _post

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

As you know We can use something like `$_POST['name'][1]`

How can we use it in `$this->input->post('name')` ?

Codeigniter post function isn't two dimensional. I think we can not pass second argument to post function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported in `Php(<v5.4)` just to `$this->input->post('name')[0]`, so there are several ways to get the values:

-use [list](http://php.net/list) function:

```
list($day) = $this->input->post("name");
```

-use loop, for example`foreach`:

```
 $foreach($this->input->post("name") as $nameData){
   echo $nameData;
 }
```

- just to set array into variable and take value:

```
$name = $this->input->post("name");
echo $name[0];
```

Comment: FYI since PHP 5.4 you can actually do that.